# Save Image in MySQL via C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, image-upload

I have a client application in C#, which is meant to take in the location of an image `(DataType: VarChar)`. This application is then supposed to invoke a web service, which in turn will store the Image (NOT the location) in a local MySQL Database.

The problem is, I realized that i am able to pass all the other data from the form to the database EXCEPT for the image...Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

ps - I know that a lot of you will be suggesting me to save the images in a file system rather than on the database itself....but the thing is, my database is not that big anyways so saving the images on the database itself will not be that big of a deal hopefully :)

Here is my table in MySQL,

```
create table testImage(
id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar(50),
age int,
image blob,
primary key(id));
```

And here is the `WebMethod` which is meant to insert the data into the table...it works when the `image` field is commented out.

```
[WebMethod]
        public string sendDataToMySql(string get_name, int get_age, byte[] buffer)
        {
            string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                  "DATABASE=test;" +
                  "UID=root;" +
                  "PASSWORD=password;";

            string name_new = get_name;
            int age_new = get_age;
            byte[] buffer_new = buffer;


            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", connection);
            command.CommandText = "insert into testdata(name, age, image) values(@name, @age, @image);";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name_new);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age_new);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", buffer_new);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            return "Task Performed!";

        }
```

Comment: blob storage you may need to do a BinaryWriter let me double check also how are you generating the byte data.. need to see the code where you do this to make sure you are generating the byte[] properly

Comment: The image is stored as a BLOB...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to declare the `buffer_new` variable at all, you can simply use the `buffer` parameter as it is.

my guess is that you should assign the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Blob` data type to the `@Image` parameter not just `AddWithValue`...

check here for a full example: [Insert blob into MySQL](http://www.programmingado.net/a-141/Insert-blob-into-MySQL.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! The link was a great help! But I am kind of confused about something. The last code snippet given on that link....why is that necessary? Plus, how do I reference `FileToArray`, `MySQL_File_Save` and `MimeType`...?

Comment: The link appears to be dead now.

Answer (score 1):

Blob is a hexadecimal value

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

One way is to pass the byte array to a hex string in insert query without using Parameters.Add ("@ Fileimage" MySqlDbType.MediumBlob);

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=bd_prueba;Uid=root;Pwd=Intel-IT;");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\proyectos2.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte[] rawData = new byte[fs.Length];        
fs.Read(rawData, 0, (int)fs.Length);
fs.Close();
//byte[] to HEX STRING
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(rawData);
//'F3-F5-01-A3' to 'F3F501A3'
hex = hex.Replace("-", "");

if(con.State == con.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
//Standart VALUE HEX x'F3F501A3'
string SQL = @"INSERT INTO tabla(id,fileimage) VALUES ('stringhex',x'"+hex+"')";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;            
cmd.CommandText = SQL;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(con.State == con.Open)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.BufferedStream bf = new BufferedStream(httpFile.InputStream);
byte[] buffer = new byte[bf.Length];   
bf.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
```

then pass buffer in to your input statement.  The datatype needs to be BLOB to handle it. 
You will need to get the mime type as well and have a filter of what mime types you want to support otherwise you could have all kinds of trouble with what goes in the database.

```
private string getFileExtension(string mimetype)
{
    mimetype = mimetype.Split('/')[1].ToLower();
    Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
    hTable.Add("pjpeg","jpg");
    hTable.Add("jpeg","jpg");
    hTable.Add("gif","gif");
    hTable.Add("x-png","png");
    hTable.Add("bmp","bmp");

    if(hTable.Contains(mimetype))
    {
        return (string)hTable[mimetype];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }           
}
```