# C# Binary conversion of document fails

Tags: c#, binary, byte, blob

I'm trying to put a document from my computer into a BLOB column in a MySQL database.

I have tried converting the .doc file into a `byte[]` array, but it keeps saving `[BLOB - 13 B]` (which is `system.byte[]` as a string) to the database instead of the actual bytes.

I don't know which part fails, i have tried multiple converting methods and stuck with this one since:

```
int curr = 0;
foreach (string path in documenteFinal)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] fileData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into documents values(null, '" + documenteFinal[curr] + "', '" + fileData + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
    { break; }

    curr++;
}
```

Comment: You should use parameterized queries instead, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235835/869621

Comment: Where is your connection string?  What line in code if failing?

Comment: @KevinGosse    That was the problem! Thank you! I always did the query like that and did not think about the problems like this one.

Comment: @jdweng        it was the wrongfully written query, as Kevin and BoredomOverload pointed out

Comment: The real error is due to writing binary data.  You added a double quotes around the data which the database treaty as a string instead of a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to tell your query that it is writing to a Blob Field and you're not just trying to store the `ToString()` representation of `fileData`.

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to achieve what you are trying to do using parameterized queries:

```
int curr = 0;
foreach (string path in documenteFinal)
{
    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO documents VALUES(null,'" + documenteFinal[curr] + "',@File)", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@File", MySqlDbType.VarBinary, fileBytes.Length).Value = fileBytes;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();

    curr++;
}
```

Comment: This made it!! Thank you!   
I did the mistake of trying `MessageBox.show(fileData.toString())` and i thought that the file was not read correctly, did not think about the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should have add a `0x` before binary data and remove the *single quotes*, try this line in place of yours:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into documents values(null, '" + documenteFinal[curr] + "', 0x" + fileData + ")";
```

I suggest however to try this more compact source code that makes use of the mysql native `LOAD_FILE` function:

```
 foreach (string path in documenteFinal) {
    try {
          connection.Open();
          MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
          cmd.CommandText = $"insert into documents values(null, '{path}', LOAD_FILE('{path}'))";
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          connection.Close();
    } catch(Exception) { break; }
  }
```

Comment: for the `0x` i get a MySql exception, (maybe I have an outdated MySql.dll, I had it about one year ago) and the `LOAD_FILE` throws this:  
`Column 'document' cannot be null.`     
The thing is one of the .doc's is purposely corrupted so I could test it out, and it throws exception on that, but works like a charm for the rest, so the answer is actually really good and I did not know the brackeys could do that on the query(saves me from a lot of quotes)

Comment: yes, it is a C# 6 feature called "string interpolation", and it is a very useful feature :)